# Online Data Model Design resources

Tags: database-design, design-pattern

So I was reading [this transcript](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/06/video-office-hours-20170607-with-transcriptions/?utm_source=Brent%20Ozar%20Unlimited%C2%AE%20List&utm_campaign=1e317c66de-RSS_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_8e3e861dd9-1e317c66de-296456429&goal=0_8e3e861dd9-1e317c66de-296456429&mc_cid=1e317c66de&mc_eid=a9a1d9a662) from Brent Ozar and co. And in the question about normalization Richie talks about a book demonstrating different data model designs across verticals. Are there any online communities that exist for the discussion / critique of data models / ERDs? Had a quick Google but couldn't find anything meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

The author they were discussing was [Louis Davidson](https://www.amazon.com/Louis-Davidson/e/B001K80LFK) (Amazon).

They then switched to [Data Model Design Patterns](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=+Data+Model+Design+Patterns) (in general; on Amazon).

This leads me to the conclusion that you are possibly looking for these three books:

- [The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 1: A Library of Universal Data Models for All Enterprises](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471353485)
- [The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 2: A Library of Data Models for Specific Industries](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471380237)
- [The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 3: Universal Patterns for Data Modeling (Volume 3)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470178450)